# regex to find characters in a filename

Tags: regex

i have a bunch of filenames (an example is below) and would like to find all files that contain the phrase "_pn".

i 'm trying to remove the "-pn" at the end of the filenames by finding all instances and replacing it with a blank space.

Adam Nyquist - Never Gonna Stop (Tom Chubb Remix)_pn.mp3

What regex expression can do this for me? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried ^(.*?(\b_pn\b)[^$]*)$ but this didnt work

Comment: Could try .*\_pn.*

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer..

```
\b(?=\W*[_pn])\w+\b
```

Comment: This doesn't match what you think it does. See: https://regex101.com/r/LHtkzD/1

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
^.+_pn\b.+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Ffydwu/1)

---

If you want to remove `_pn`:

- Find: `^(.+)_pn(\b.+)$`
- Replace: `$1$2`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qioeW6/1)

Or simpler:

- Find: `_pn\b`
- Replace: `NOTHING`